# MySQL query error for a particular colum

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP file that recieves an associative array of name, email and password.

When I try to insert the data using PHP MySQL query in this PHP file, it flashes following error

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@gmail.com, qweqwe)' at line 1"

My PHP code is as follows:

```
$data = array
(
    'name' => $name,
    'email' => $email,
    'password' => $password,
);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `other_doktrs` (`dnme` ,`emyl` ,`paswrd`) VALUES ($name, $email, $password)");
```

I tried to change the order of column names but it was of no help.

thanks in advance

Comment: Surround the variables with single quotes... `('$name', '$email', '$password')`

Answer (score 1):

You still need to put quotes around strings if you want to use the old direct (and SQL Injection prone) methods:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `other_doktrs` (`dnme` ,`emyl` ,`paswrd`) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$password')");
```

You really should look at PDO though and prepared statements. Much much safer - and as a bonus when you pass params, you don't need the quotes. Irony huh? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `other_doktrs` (`dnme` ,`emyl` ,`paswrd`) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$password')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `other_doktrs` (`dnme` ,`emyl` ,`paswrd`) VALUES ("'.$name.'"," '.$email.'", "'.$password.'")");
```

passing query with quotes.

Hope this helps you.